# Trying to add a tuple to a list and the character ' gets added breaking the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, tuples

I am trying to make a simple password manager (in python) and I have already made some code that stores the service name and the randomly generated password in a tuple. It is just a normal txt file. The issue I am having is that when I read the file line by line, and get the tuple (it looks like this - ("YouTube", "vwL4F7MC94VBERtS7xGdL2IugT2b3n!H"), and append it to my list, it shows up as this:

```
['("YouTube", "vwL4F7MC94VBERtS7xGdL2IugT2b3n!H")', '("Google", "tcOtnrc6ES9ZH%PdPb$m%8fvOT4uZiJt")']
```

I need it to look like this:

```
[("YouTube", "vwL4F7MC94VBERtS7xGdL2IugT2b3n!H"), ("Google", "tcOtnrc6ES9ZH%PdPb$m%8fvOT4uZiJt")]
```

As you can see the quotes appear before and after both tuples which means that when I go to list the service names, It doesn't list them properly as it thinks that the '(' is the first item in the tuple when I just want it to list for example: Google, Youtube. I have everything else working in my code and even tried manually changing list and it works fine. I tried to just remove the character ' but that doesn't work as those quote marks act like the quote marks around a string. Here is my code that reads the file and appends it to the list as a tuple:

```
#opening data
data = open("D:\Documents\Password Manager\data.txt", "r")

for line in data.readlines():
    list_services_passwords.append(line)
    print(line)

print(list_services_passwords)

data.close()
```

EDIT:

Here is the data.txt file content:

("YouTube", "vwL4F7MC94VBERtS7xGdL2IugT2b3n!H")

("Google", "tcOtnrc6ES9ZH%PdPb$m%8fvOT4uZiJt")

Comment: Do you manage the way the data is saved in the file? If you have control over that part you could change it to another structure that would be easier to parse. If not you will have to parse it differently as it returns texts, not tuples. Can you add to the question the file content?

Comment: yes I will do that now

Comment: Think about what a line is in a text file - it is a string. I would suggest that maybe ou need a different format for your data.txt file - maybe store the data as two fields space seperated, and then you can easily extract the fields (using split() and add them to your list.
By storing them as tuples in your data.txt you are just making things more complex.
PS - I would recommaend not using `eval` to convert your text - don't get into bad habits.

Comment: You're not appending a tuple -- you're appending a string that happens to look like a tuple.

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to python, how would I go about extracting the information into a tuple in a list if the data.txt looked like this:

Comment: May I recommend the `csv` module?

Comment: YouTube vwL4F7MC94VBERtS7xGdL2IugT2b3n!H


Google tcOtnrc6ES9ZH%PdPb$m%8fvOT4uZiJt
On separate lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ast

with open("D:\Documents\Password Manager\data.txt", "r") as fp:
    list_services_passwords = fp.readlines()

list_services_passwords = [ast.literal_eval(p) for p in list_services_passwords]
```

Output:

```
[('YouTube', 'vwL4F7MC94VBERtS7xGdL2IugT2b3n!H'), ('Google', 'tcOtnrc6ES9ZH%PdPb$m%8fvOT4uZiJt')]
```

Comment: Thank you that is extactly what I was looking for

Comment: For me the output looks like this:
[(('YouTube', 'vwL4F7MC94VBERtS7xGdL2IugT2b3n!H'),),
 ('Google', 'tcOtnrc6ES9ZH%PdPb$m%8fvOT4uZiJt')]

Comment: whats the file content?

Comment: Here is the data.txt file content:

("YouTube", "vwL4F7MC94VBERtS7xGdL2IugT2b3n!H")

("Google", "tcOtnrc6ES9ZH%PdPb$m%8fvOT4uZiJt")

Comment: I got this result isn't it correct `(('YouTube', 'vwL4F7MC94VBERtS7xGdL2IugT2b3n!H'),
 ('Google', 'tcOtnrc6ES9ZH%PdPb$m%8fvOT4uZiJt'))`

Comment: make sure every tuple is present on the next line and not the same line.

Comment: I got extra brackets around the youtube tuple and an extra comma.
````

Comment: like my comment above

Comment: I did (see edit on original question, i included it at the bottom)